# Group by id and get avg time delta between grouped rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-14

I have a table with ids and timestamps:

```
postgres=> select id_user, date_seconds from orders.orders order by id_user limit 10;
           id_user            |    date_seconds
------------------------------+---------------------
 00D4jzHHesfCXGO6VQfUun9JcCW2 | 2021-09-20 02:00:00
 00D4jzHHesfCXGO6VQfUun9JcCW2 | 2021-10-06 02:00:00
 00D4jzHHesfCXGO6VQfUun9JcCW2 |
 00d9QGWjmbYdRTGw4h4GynhDp2K2 | 2021-10-01 02:00:00
 00OI3ruCKeOFdIro11eVNcfp84A2 | 2021-10-06 02:00:00
 00OI3ruCKeOFdIro11eVNcfp84A2 | 2021-08-24 02:00:00
 00qwpdw23BSEBGkfJhR4Hb7Kg1v2 | 2021-09-17 02:00:00
 00qwpdw23BSEBGkfJhR4Hb7Kg1v2 | 2021-09-20 02:00:00
 00qwpdw23BSEBGkfJhR4Hb7Kg1v2 | 2021-10-04 02:00:00
 00qwpdw23BSEBGkfJhR4Hb7Kg1v2 | 2021-08-20 02:00:00
(10 rows)
```

As you can see, one `id_user` can appear multiple times in this table.

I would like to group this table by `id_user`. However, I would also want to have the average **delta time** of the `date_seconds` column between the rows of that particular `id_user`.

I figured I might need to use the `LAG` psql function, but I am unsure how or if I`m even on the right track here.

Examples as suggested by the comments:

Suppose I have the following table:

```
INSERT INTO orders(id_user, ordered_at) VALUES
('1', '2021-09-20 02:00:00'),
('1', '2021-10-06 02:00:00'),
('2', '2021-10-01 02:00:00'),
('3', '2021-10-06 02:00:00'),
('3', '2021-08-24 03:00:00'),
('4', '2021-08-20 02:00:00'),
('4', '2021-09-17 02:00:00'),
('4', '2021-09-20 02:00:00'),
('4', '2021-10-04 02:00:00');
```

The desired result would be the following:
The avg time between a user's orders can be calculated as follows:
AVG( time interval between orders )

```
example: id_user 1: AVG( 2021-09-20 02:00:00 - 2021-10-06 02:00:00) which equals 16 days and 0 hours interval
```

```
example: id user 4: ACG( (2021-08-20 02:00:00 - 2021-09-17 02:00:00) , (2021-09-17 02:00:00 - 2021-09-20 02:00:00) , (2021-09-20 02:00:00 - 2021-10-04 02:00:00)  )
example: id user 4: AVG( (interval '28 days') , (interval '3 days') , (interval '14 days')  )
example: id user 4: 28+3+14 / 3 = 15 --> result should be interval '15 days'

postgres=> SELECT magic(ordered_at) as avg_timedelta, id_user from orders where id_user='4' group by id_user;
            id_user            |    avg_timedelta
------------------------------+---------------------
              4                |      15 days
```

Comment: Which id appears multiple times in your example?...can you add the table definition of the `orders` table to your post please?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct your table, some sample data and your desired result - help us to help you! And what does one do in the case where there's no date_seconds field value?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I added some examples in the question, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
select id_user, (max(ordered_at)-min(ordered_at)) / (count(1)-1)
from orders
group by id_user
having count(1) > 1;
```

If you want to use lead (or lag) instead, you can determine the duration between two consecutive rows and then apply avg on that set:

```
with t as (
    select id_user, ordered_at
         , lead(ordered_at) over (partition by id_user order by ordered_at) as ld_ordered_at
    from orders
)
select id_user, avg(ld_ordered_at - ordered_at) 
from t
where ld_ordered_at is not null
group by id_user;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=caa07900f80e69bcfdfcccf4e49d779e)

The idea behind the first solution is that:

```
(x2-x1)+(x3-x2)+...+(x_n+1-x_n) <=>
(-x1+(x2-x2)+(x3-x3)+...+(x_n-1-x_n-1)+x_n) <=>
(x_n-x1)
```

and then divide with n-1 to get the average

Comment: The simple first solution! (Plus how ever the OP want to deal with NULL values.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, the first solution has to be slightly adjusted. I'll update

Comment: Note that `count(1)` is actually slightly slower than `count(*)` in Postgres (and identical in performance for all other DBMS)

Comment: Old habit, once upon a time in a galaxy far far away someone told me that COUNT(*) had to look up something in the catalogue for that DBMS and that it, therefore, should be avoided. I don't even know whether that was true or not back then, but I have been using COUNT(1) ever since:-)

Comment: Thank you! Very 'elegant solution'.